# Trying to understand some c++ code that iterates backwards through a char array

Tags: c++

I'm following a C++ tutorial and I'm trying to walk my way through each line, but I'm stumped. So far I have a char array that I'm trying to iterate through backwards using pointers and a while loop. I've added in comments to try and understand what each bit is doing. Can someone confirm my understanding please?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char text[] = "hello";

    int nChars = sizeof(text) - 1; // finds the size of the array (equals 6), and subtracts 1. "Hello" has 5 letters, but there's an added 6th element called the stop element.

    cout << nChars << endl;

    char* pStart = text; // pStart will Point to first value in array.
    char* pEnd = text + nChars - 1; // takes the first element in the array, adds the amount of additional elements, and subtracts 1 from the end.

    while (pStart < pEnd)
    {
        char save = *pStart; // Save the first element (h) in "hello".


        *pStart = *pEnd; // Takes the beginning element (h), adds the remaining elements, removes the termination character (nChars - 1) then sets the end as the beginning

        pStart++; // Increment through the char array with the end as the beginning, working through 'o', increment to 'l', then 'l', then 'e', then 'h'.
        pEnd--; // 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The missing part is what to do with `save` after `*pStart = *pEnd;`

Comment: The `-1` in `text + nChars - 1;` seems redundant to the one in `int nChars = sizeof(text) - 1;`.

Comment: I would recommend adding "`cout << "Curr saved val: " << save << "\n";`" after the line starting with `char save` so that you can have a better idea of what it's doing.

Comment: The line with `*pStart=*pEnd;` does not add or remove anything. And this code does not iterate backwards through the string.

Comment: ***I'm following a C++ tutorial and I'm trying to walk my way through each line*** If you knew how to use a debugger you could have it execute the code 1 line at a time then look at what happens to the variables after each line.